# Get latitude and longitude from google map share link using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to get latitude and longitude from google map share link.

Link like this `https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/RAKBANK/@25.1134555,55.3761924,17.5z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x358ae5fd319e6a64!2sSemmer+Villas!8m2!3d25.1151977!4d55.3821136!3m4!1s0x0:0x3fdded92629b7214!8m2!3d25.1131947!4d55.3759586`

I searched google and don't find the answer

Comment: Explain what language you're using, how you want the latitude and longitude. Provide a lot more information than this please.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/brc5ec0r/)

```
var url = 'https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/RAKBANK/@25.1120342,55.3745323,15z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x358ae5fd319e6a64!2sSemmer+Villas!8m2!3d25.1151977!4d55.3821136!3m4!1s0x0:0x3fdded92629b7214!8m2!3d25.1131947!4d55.3759586';

var urlParts = url.split( '/' );
var getLatLng = urlParts[6].replace('@','');
getLatLng = getLatLng.split( ',' );

var geo = {
    lat: getLatLng[0],
  lng: getLatLng[1]
}

console.log(geo);
```

Is this what you want? It will only grab the Lat and Lng for the Map Center which is enclosed in the URL.

If you are looking for the Location of RAKBANK, you would need to use Google Geolocation to return the Address and/or lat lng.